# Determinant and generalized eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let A, B be two symmetric positive-definite matrices. Let $\lambda_i$ be the generalized eigenvalues of the pencil (A,B). Can we write function $\log\frac{|A|}{|B|}$ (where $|\cdot|$ stands for determinant) in terms of $\lambda_i$? 
thanks!

Comment: Hint: determinant is product of eigenvalues of a matrix. Furthermore: $\log(a \times b)=\log a + \log b$

Comment: thanks, in fact I have a probably dumb question here: how the eigenvalues of A and B is associated to the generalized eigenvalues of (A,B)? If I get this, I think I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: Let $B=R^2$. Then $$\det{(R^{-1}AR^{-1})}=\det{(AR^{-2})}=\det{(A)}\det{(R^{-2})}=\frac{\det{(A)}}{\det{(B)}}$$ (**verify!!**)

How are generalized eigenvalues of the pencil $(A,B)$ related to the eigenvalues of $(R^{-1}AR^{-1})$?